# Powershell - Do while

Tags: powershell

I have a little question regarding my do while script
Right now when $BackuptoPM -eq 'rejected' I got the message tat upload failed and afterward I get the message that the upload completed. upload completed should be only when the loop is ended.
How can I fix this that when the script failed I will get only the right message?

```
do {
                $p = Get-VSTeamRelease -id $ReleaseID
                $BackuptoPM = $p.environments[0].status 
                $BackuptoALM = $p.environments[1].status 
                $time = Get-Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y %R:%S"
                write-host "Upload to PM is in progress...$time"
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
                if ($BackuptoPM -eq 'rejected') {
                    write-host "Upload to PM failed" -ForegroundColor Red
                    break
                }
            }
            while ($BackuptoPM -ne 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -ne 'rejected')

            write-host
            write-host "Upload to PM is completed" -ForegroundColor Green
            write-host
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is a bit strange here..
Inside the loop, you break out if `$BackuptoPM -eq 'rejected'` and then write "Upload to PM is completed", no matter what happened..

I would rather create a loop where you set a maximum number of tries, and afterwards report on what went wrong or not.

Something like this perhaps:

```
# as example try 3 times
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 3; $i++) {   
    $time = Get-Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y %R:%S"
    Write-Host "Upload to PM is in progress...$time"
    $p = Get-VSTeamRelease -id $ReleaseID
    $BackuptoPM  = $p.environments[0].status 
    $BackuptoALM = $p.environments[1].status 
    # break if both succeeded
    if ($BackuptoPM -eq 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -ne 'rejected') {
        break
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}

# now test what happened
if ($BackuptoPM -eq 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -ne 'rejected') {
    Write-Host "Upload to PM is completed" -ForegroundColor Green
}
elseif ($BackuptoPM -ne 'succeeded') {
    Write-Host "Upload to PM failed" -ForegroundColor Red
}
else {
    Write-Host "Upload to ALM failed" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

---

Of course, you can also use a `while` loop and have it run for a maximum time period like for instance 1 hour

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddHours(1)
while ((Get-Date) -lt $refDate){
    $time = Get-Date -UFormat "%d/%m/%Y %R:%S"
    Write-Host "Upload to PM is in progress...$time"
    $p = Get-VSTeamRelease -id $ReleaseID
    $BackuptoPM  = $p.environments[0].status 
    $BackuptoALM = $p.environments[1].status 
    # break if both succeeded
    if ($BackuptoPM -eq 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -ne 'rejected') {
        break
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used a while because I don't know how much time the upload will take..
I trigger a release and sometimes it can take 20 or more. or it can be failed after 1 minutes.
I need to run in a loop until ($BackuptoPM -ne 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -ne 'rejected'). or the upload to PM will failed.
How can I change your solution in order to use my use case?

Comment: @Bandit Then at least change to `until ($BackuptoPM -eq 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -ne 'rejected')` and remove the test that breaks your do-loop so it will only finish on success. This _could_ lead to a never ending loop though, that's why I suggested to loop until a maximum number of tries have passed.

Comment: I want to use your solution but I cannot know how many tries to use. Sometimes its takes 15 minutes and sometimes 30 or 40. What can I do in this case?

Comment: @Bandit Would my edit suit your case better?

Comment: Just to know, My original script is working unless the part if there is an error it will display 2 messages. failed and completed. It is very rare that the first part is failing (PM). Actually the second part (ALM) should failed. Why I cannot use the original script?

Comment: @Bandit Your code will always display 2 messages if upload failed, because [1] **inside** the loop you write a failure message and [2] **after** the loop you don't check anything, but simply do `write-host "Upload to PM is completed" -ForegroundColor Green` whether it failed or not.

Comment: Not always 2 messages will be displayed. Only then the if failed. I am waiting for ($BackuptoPM -eq 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -eq 'rejected' ) and then display that upload completed. Just in case that $BackuptoPM -eq 'rejected' I want to brake and not waiting 1 hour

Comment: What will the different between while to until?

@Bandit Then at least change to until ($BackuptoPM -eq 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -ne 'rejected')

Comment: As I saw the different between while to until is that:
Do While keeps running as long as the condition is true.
Do Until keeps running as long as the condition is false.
In my case ($BackuptoPM -ne 'succeeded' -and $BackuptoALM -ne 'rejected') is true and when it will be true the loop will end. so why I need to use until and not while?

Comment: @Bandit These are just different ways of looping until a certain condition is met. While **starts** the loop by examining this condition, Do..Until examines it at the **end** of the loop. If you have an extra condition to break out of that loop, use the `break` statement. That's all. Just do some experimenting with loops